# how to move to another php page

Tags: php, header

I made an `add.php` that adds some things to a database; after that I want to move to `show.php`. I have to send an id parameter with it.  This is my code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include('../../includes/connect.php');

$title = $_POST['title'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

$query = "insert into news (title, subject, image) values ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[subject]', '$image')";   
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$data = array(
        'id' => $id
        );
$base = '../../show.php';
$url = $base. '?' . http_build_query($data);
header("Location : $url");
exit();
?>
```

But nothing happened, I'm still stuck in `add.php`.

Comment: Are you sure `show.php` is in that directory? (`../../show.php`)

Comment: Whenever something doesn't work, enable `error_reporting`.

Comment: I believe you can or have to use `values ('$title','$subject', '$image')";` instead of `values ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[subject]', '$image')";`. I hope someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Fred That's right. It wouldn't make much difference though, as there is no sanitization.

Comment: @Campari Thanks for that, it's good information to know.

Comment: You don't need the `ob_start()` here btw.

Comment: Please escape variables used in a query, not `addslashes()`. Also consider using prepared statements.

Comment: @Jack what do you mean by prepared statements?

Comment: @Campari I noticed this now and think that it wouldn't work anyway, or would it? This `$_POST[title]','$_POST[subject]` contains no apostrophes for the bracketed variables, which one would think it would need to be `$_POST['title']','$_POST['subject']`.

Comment: @fred that actually works, believe it or not :)

Comment: @Jack Oh, I didn't know that (till now). I was sure that it would've thrown an error.

Comment: Look up [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and find out. Beats the crap out of having to do manual escaping :)

Comment: @Jack Thanks (for the link) Jack, I will do that. And it sure does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the whitespace between `Location` and the colon, like this:

```
header("Location: $url");
```

In the [Location header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) there should be no space in between; perhaps that's causing some error.

Comment: Your argument could be better with a verbatim quote from the RFC :)

Comment: @Jack why is better ?

Comment: Eh, because it gives the answer authority instead of being guesswork :)

Comment: @Jack That's right, originally it was guesswork :P. Now I added the quote from the RFC.

Answer (score 2):

`header("Location : $url");`

I have never seen `Location :` with a space. Try it without the space:

`header("Location: $url");`

Could u provide the data of the variable `$url`?